# Get result of the script tag (informer) into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script as an informer to display a list of hotels. I want to change the limit with JS and get the result. If I try to use fetch() I got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and it returns some code. Is it possible somehow to get the results of this informer into a variable?

```
<script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?iata=PAR&type=full&currency=rub&host=search.hotellook.com&marker=77410.&limit=10" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you can prevent CORS policy error. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the list of hotels from `TravelPayouts` you have another endpoint for that which is: `https://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json`.

In your case you can try with this URL:

`https://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json?query=moskow&lang=en&lookFor=both&limit=[your-limit-number]`

You can make a .ajax request and it's should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     crossDomain: true,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     url: 'https://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json?query=moskow&lang=en&lookFor=both&limit=10',
     success: function(jsondata){
        console.log(jsondata);
     }
});
```

`JSONP` is a method for sending JSON data without worrying about cross-domain issues.

For more information you can found on:

https://support.travelpayouts.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000343268-Hotels-data-API#3